# Edit Existing Github project in Visual Studios

Tags: c++, github, visual-studio-2013

I have cloned my team's github repository using Visual Studios 2013 team explorer. My team is using many different IDEs to work on this project (gvim, xcode, eclipse with c++ extensions, etc). The project includes an "includes" folder (for .h files), a "src" folder (for .cpp files), a "tests" folder for our unit tests, an "obj" folder (contains something called main.o), and two library folders "UnitTest++" and "SDL2".

My question is how can I view all these folders as they exist in our github repository and edit the files within these folders in Visual Studios 2013 (and if possible compile them with visual studios)?

Comment: What works best for me with my preferred IDE (Eclipse CDT), is to create one directory where I keep the actual repository (git, svn, etc.), and another one where I'm keeping my private project workspace (I think the term used for VS is _'Solution'_). All of the code from the repository is imported/linked into (virtual) folders in the actual projects. The point is, get the workspace/solution/project management files outside the repository.

Comment: I know what you mean, but my overall problem is importing the folder contents automatically (I can import individual files, but if a new file was added by another team member, that would not show up). Also, I am not quite sure how to add in the library folders.

Comment: I'm afraid VS misses the capability to synchronize virtual folders from imported projects, but even for Eclipse I have to do this manually (though there's a GIT plugin that would do this right). Is it essential you use the VS2013 IDE? **Note:** You can use e.g. Eclipse as IDE, and use the same underlying toolchain, if that should be your point.

Comment: I may be able to use eclipse kepler, but I only have it set up for Java, not C++

Comment: IMHO the easiest way is, to have a separate Eclipse CDT installation (on windows I suspect). But you can also install the necessary stuff for an existing Eclipse instance, going to `Help->Install New Software`, choose your primary [Kepler download site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler), and lookup for `Programming Languages -> C/C++ Development tools` and related. Git support can be found in the `Collaboration` category. I hope this helps you out!